# App engine game score/leaderboards design - how to do better?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an existing Android game that uses GAE to total scores and generate leaderboards.  However, I am seeing all sorts of horrid weirdness even with 10 simultaneous users.

Each game lasts 3 minutes.  The timing is enforced by a synchronized CRON entry which runs a task.

**Step 0**:

- clients submit scores
- GAE checks user exists, and creates a temporary model object containing username+score/etc
- GAE spawns a task to update user statistics (how many games played, total score/etc)

**Step 1** (submit +5 seconds)... launched by CRON:

- collect all temp user scores
- rank them and put them into perm storage for that game
- update "previous game" keyed model pointer to point to latest "previous game"
- update "current game" to point to next available game board

**Step 2**: (submit + 10 seconds):

- ranked scores available to clients.
- clients start to pull scores (fetch "last game" 'pointer' key, deref and serve results)

**Step 3** : (submit + 20 seconds):

- clients start to pull next game

**Step 4**: (submit + 25 seconds):

- new game starts for next 2m30secs

## Problems that I am seeing:

GAE randomly does not store some/all submitted scores, or fails to retrieve some/all scores to calculate all the results for the game.

GAE sometimes serves the same board twice (ie: synchronized CRON did not run).

No errors are ever logged by GAE (wtf?).  It is like the operation just never happened, instead of some random error.  Error rate is about 2-5% at a guess, but with 480 games/day, that is a LOT of errors... which get noticed by my users!

If anyone has any suggestions on a better way to architect things, or some comments, it would be greatly appreciated !  I know I could improve things by using memcache for results and pre-converting results to a stream (because memcache uses pickle) to improve performance, but I am more interested in fixing the errors/etc.

Comment: Is your code logging errors from the datastore or ignoring them? Are you using the High Replication Datastore? If so, do you understand what "eventual consistency" means in terms of repeatable reads? Are you doing your writes and reads in transactions? How many writes per entity group are you trying to do? Do you have multithreading enabled? Is your code thread safe? Are you sure cron didn't run, or did you just not get the results you were expecting - ie if you output a logging statement first thing in your cron handler, do you see it? How many users are in one game? What is the difference be

Comment: Where's the code? And why on earth are you using cron for this?

Comment: What's the reason for storing scores in a temp model?  Based on your description it seems like you would be better off putting it straight into the datastore asynchronously and then pulling the 'ranked' results with an ordered query.  Speaking more generally, I think that decoupling your game generation/queueing from your score storage and processing would help reduce problems.

Comment: **Answers:**<br/>
1) Code is logging errors from the datastore.  At least, there is no try: around things, so any errors result in logs (I have seen this in the past).<br/>
2) High Replication Datastore.<br/>
3) Yes, I do.  I potentially need to handle a large number of simultaneous users submitting results.  I thought a 5 second window to store a single object asynchronously would be ok.<br/>
4) No transactions<br/>
5) Yes, using Python27.  Yes it is thread safe.<br/>
6) Not 100% sure, but it sure does not rotate to the next game board (sometimes), but does not throw any errors.

Comment: Code is not available.  Sorry, this is an android game I am hoping to actually make money on.  Although, at the moment I am up to about $0.20 per day less $0.12 GAE hosting costs ... lol.  I can dream!

Using CRON because I really have very little clue what I am doing.  Tasks would be better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to this is:

1. Cache queries (eg: for game board/results) in local ram and pre-json them
2. Use a Backend with async pulls to a node.js caching box that receives scores to grab the leaderboard data
3. Backend creates leaderboards, then pushes them to datastore and memcache
4. Backend relies on spawned thread that is NTP corrected and runs in lockstep with the time using sleep()
5. A cron job monitors the backend and will restart it if it crashes (because GAE won't already restart it due to infrastructure bugs)

Tried that did not work:

1. Cron job to keep time (won't always run, and won't run on time)
2. Multiple backends accepting results instead of node.js boxen
3. CloudSQL (throughput problems)